# How do i add a property to a class that is not a method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class

I am reading **eloquent JavaScript (3rd edition)** and stumbled upon Question To create a  a class **PGroup** that behaves like JavaScript **Set**.

Its add method, however, should return a new PGroup instance with the given member added and leave the old one unchanged. Similarly, delete creates a new instance without a given member and has method true or false if the element is in the array.

The class should work for values of any type, not just strings. It does not have to be efficient when used with large amounts of values.

The constructor shouldn’t be part of the class’s interface (though you’ll definitely want to use it internally). Instead, there is an empty instance, PGroup.empty, that can be used as a starting value.

Why do you need only one PGroup.empty value, rather than having a function that creates a new, empty map every time?

```
class PGroup {
  // Your code here
}

let a = PGroup.empty.add("a");
let ab = a.add("b");
let b = ab.delete("a");

console.log(b.has("b"));
// → true
console.log(a.has("b"));
// → false
console.log(b.has("a"));
// → false
```

This is my solution

```
class PGroup {
  // Your code here
  constructor() {
    this.array = [];
  }
  has(val) {
    return this.array.includes(val); 
  }
  add(val) {
    if (!this.has(val)) {
       let group = new PGroup();
        for (let el of this.array) {
          group.array.push(el);
        }
       group.array.push(val);
      return group;
    }
    return this;
  }
  
  delete(val) {
    if (this.has(val)) {
        let array = this.array.filter(v => v !== val);
       let group = new PGroup();
      for (let el of array) {
          group.array.push(el);
        }
      return group;
    }
  }
  static get empty() {
    return new PGroup();
  }
}

let a = PGroup.empty.add("a");
let ab = a.add("b");
let b = ab.delete("a");

console.log(b.has("b"));
// → true
console.log(a.has("b"));
// → false
console.log(b.has("a"));
// → false
```

And this is the author solution

```
class PGroup {
  constructor(members) {
    this.members = members;
  }

  add(value) {
    if (this.has(value)) return this;
    return new PGroup(this.members.concat([value]));
  }

  delete(value) {
    if (!this.has(value)) return this;
    return new PGroup(this.members.filter(m => m !== value));
  }

  has(value) {
    return this.members.includes(value);
  }
}

PGroup.empty = new PGroup([]);

let a = PGroup.empty.add("a");
let ab = a.add("b");
let b = ab.delete("a");

console.log(b.has("b"));
// → true
console.log(a.has("b"));
// → false
console.log(b.has("a"));
// → false
```

My question are as follows:

1. Why do you need only one PGroup.empty value, rather than having a function that creates a new, empty map every time?
2. Is my empty method the same as the author's empty property (let's ignore the fact that the author passed an empty array to the constructor)?
3. Why is the author PGroup.empty property outside of the class in the authors code?
4. How do i add a property to a class that is not a method in JavaScript class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why do you need only one `PGroup.empty` value, rather than having a function that creates a new, empty map every time?

You don't **need** one, but if `PGroup` is supposed to represent an immutable data structure, you don't need more than one empty one, since all empty ones would be exactly the same.

> 2.Is my empty method the same as the author's empty property (let's ignore the fact that the author passed an empty array to the constructor)?

No, the author's version is a data property that returns the same object every time (`PGroup.empty === PGroup.empty` is `true`), yours is an accessor property that creates a new instance every time.

> 3. Why is the author PGroup.empty property outside of the class in the authors code?

Probably because the book was written before the [static class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features) proposal reached maturity providing the syntax necessary to do it declaratively.

> 4. How do i add a property to a class that is not a method in JavaScript class?

The property you're talking about is, specifically, a property of the `PGroup` constructor function, not `PGroup` instances, so it's a "static" property. As of the static class fields proposal reaching maturity, you do it like this:

```
class PGroup {
    static empty = new PGroup([]);
    // ...
}
```

Static class fields (and a couple of related proposals) only landed in the specification recently (they'll be in the ES2022 snapshot next June). But they're supported by current versions of all non-obsolete browsers (thus, not Internet Explorer or Legacy Edge [but they're in the Chromium-based Edge]).

Prior to that, you'd do it the way the author did it.

Comment: Why is `PGroup.empty === PGroup.empty`..under the hood they are both returning a new instance of PGroup which are different object.

Comment: @lawalolawale - Just to be clear, I said that's true of the *author's* version; you're describing the behavior of your version, which is different. `PGroup.empty = new PGroup([]);` does `new PGroup([])` **once** and assigns that object to `PGroup.empty`. Accessing the property gives you that object. It's exactly like `let a = {}; console.log(a === a); // true`.

Comment: what if u want to create a private property or public property similar to typescript own. How do you do that??

Comment: @lawalolawale - For a public property, you do the same as above but without `static`: `theProperty = initialValue;`. For a private one, you use the `#` sigil: `#theProperty = initialValue;`. Those are both covered [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). (All of this is also covered in my book [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev/).)